# Passing srcset to image attachment method

Tags: images

I would like to pass values of `wp_get_attachment_image_srcset` to the `wp_get_attachment_image` method and wonder how is this possible without hardcoding the HTML image tag itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say I've tested this but here's what you could to, it should in theory work.

The `wp_get_attachment_image()` functions 4th parameter is an array of attributes. You should be able to pass what you get returned from `wp_get_attachment_image_srcset()` to the attribute parameter as follows, *sort of similar* to the [example seen on the docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_srcset/#user-contributed-notes).

```
$image_attrs    = '';
$image_id       = 123;
$image_size     = 'full';
$image_srcset   = wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( $image_id, $image_size );

if( ! empty( $image_srcset ) ) {

    $image_attrs = array(
        'srcset' => esc_attr( $image_srcset ),
    );

}

$image_html = wp_get_attachment_image( $image_id, $image_size, false, $image_attrs );
```